# How to create 8-bit PNG from BufferedImage?

Tags: java, png, bufferedimage

I have a Java program that creates composite png images that contain only black pixels and 100% transparent pixels. I am trying to reduce the size of these composites as much as possible and I notice that ImageIO.write always outputs 32 bit PNG's. I would like to instead save them as 8-bit considering that the images will only have two colors total but I don't think there is a way to do this with the standard Java functions.

Does anyone know of any pre-built functions that will create an 8-bit png from a BufferedImage? Any other advice to reduce the size of these png's is welcome too!

Comment: What happens if you save them as GIF?  (I ask because it is limited to 256 colors.)

Comment: On average, the 32-bit PNG are smaller than a GIF containing the same pixels.

Comment: This does remind me though that you can actually reduce the number of indexed colors in GIF down to 2... again though, not sure how I would achieve this without an external function.

Comment: How are the images being loaded/used?  By other Java code under your control?

Comment: Yes, the images are generated within my own program into a blank BufferedImage.

Comment: Seem like you are referring to image output.  I am talking about the image *input.*  What is the *consumer* for the images?

Comment: The images are saved to disc and then used externally for composite filter effects.

Comment: OK if the consumers are 'many different apps. we do not control' that blows my idea of storing them in whatever format is smallest (and if needed restoring the transparency when reconstructing them).

Comment: Unfortunately yes. It looks like I may need to look into coding the output byte array myself.

Comment: In case you find it useful: http://code.google.com/p/pngj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to put this in the backseat for a bit, but I came back to it yesterday and figured out how to do it. Basically it came down to using the classes under `com.sun.imageio.plugins.png` and a custom `ImageWriteParam`.

I had to build the color tables myself (not too hard, just byte arrays). The color tables were then passed to `ImageTypeSpecifier.createIndexed`. The resulting `ImageTypeSpecifier` returned allows you to create a `BufferedImage` into which I copied the pixels.

Next, I created custom PNG headers by using `PNGMetadata` (Needed to read up a lot on the PNG specification, but overall very easy). I then created a new `IIOImage` using said metadata and the BufferedImage.

Finally, I created a `PNGImageWriter` and got the default `ImageWriteParam` from it. I then simply passed the `ImageTypeSpecifier` from before to its `setDestinationType` method. Last step was to write the PNG to disk by passing the IIOImage and the ImageWriteParam to the PNGImageWriter.

The documentation is very sparse on many of these classes but their functionality is great. By doing this, I created a minimal PNG that contained a bit depth of 1 (since there are only two colors) and this reduced the size of my PNG's by an average of 78%!!! Very much worth the effort.

Comment: The quantisation required for creating an optimal palette out of your existing high coloured image is usually the hardest step, though...

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure, but I would guess that `ImageIO` uses whatever *type* the `BufferedImage` uses. Try playing with the different types available. `TYPE_CUSTOM` and `TYPE_BYTE_BINARY` look promising.

Comment: Interesting thought but I'm not sure. It seems that TYPE_BYTE_BINARY does not support an alpha channel and I need to preserve the transparency.

I'm wondering about the TYPE_CUSTOM though. It's nice if I define the BufferedImage as TYPE_CUSTOM but how would I actually go about changing how this is interpreted by ImageIO?

Comment: I have no idea having never used TYPE_CUSTOM, the BufferedImage type was the only thing that came to mind, but I have no real answer :(